# Memory leak in dynamically creating linearlayout and textviews

Tags: android, eclipse, memory

I am having problem creating lots of `LinearLayout` and `TextView`
basically my app displays text and I dynamically create rows(`LinearLayout`) and words(`TexView`) in the corresponding row. Now my app also uses `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` so I can "change the page". I have no problem with that. The problem is when I redirect to my own activity with a new textsize it somehow leaks when adding rows.

```
 int threshold = 25;
 int tw = 0;
 LinearLayout ll = rootView.findViewById(R.id.container);
 LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(a);
  for(int x = 0;x<words.size();x++)
 {
   tw+=words.get(x).length;
   TextView tv = new TextView(a);
   tv.setText(words.get(x));
   if(tw > threshold)
   {
        ll.addView(row)  <----- this is where out of memory points me
        row = new LinearLayout(a);
        tw = 0;
        x-=1;
   }
   else
        row.addView(tv);

}
```

Now I also tried dumping the heap and analyzing with mat but the dump I am creating has an invalid header error so I don't know where the actual leak comes from other than the actual error log I have in logcat that points to the ll adding rows which I don't know if is the right place to look into.

Edited : Some added info. It seems the problem occurs when I am adjusting the row height through linearlayout params because when i set my own default which is 50 it is usually just fine. Anyone one knows the reason for this?

Comment: Probably there is a dead loop.

Comment: what do you mean by deadloop? you mean because of the x-=1? but i initialize tw to 0 so next iteration should proceed.

Comment: Why does words both have size method and length property?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop may end into a dead loop for some conditions.

For instance,if your `words` list contains a `String` which length is over `threshold`(25),the if statement(`tw > threshold`) would forever evaluate to true,and because you also minus loop count `x` by one,this is where dead loop happens.

Comment: Yeah but in my case I handled that mostly before i even added the text into the words arraylist by concatenating a - and dividing the text into two for those whose length is greater than 15. so i got that thing covered i just didn't include it because it would be long if i add all my code. Thanks for the reply